# Thunderbird: composed email font size?

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to change the font size for the whole composed e-mail to a specific font size number? i.e. similar to outlook by just highlighting all the document and select a size number.

Scenario: copying and pasting from different websites to a composed e-mail will have several font sizes/fonts. The only way I know of now is to go to each section and change the size with the big and small A to change the size.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all text and select a **paragraph format**.

[image: Thunderbird compose]

Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to **Paste Without Formatting**. This option is available also on right-click as well as Edit menu.